# No value specified for parameter 10 al cargar fecha desde MySQL en JDateChooser

Tags: java, mysql

Me encuentro entre la espada y la pared, me sale el siguiente error **No value specified for parameter 10** al querer cargar la fecha almacenada en la BD en un **JDateChooser.**
El error ocurre cuando cargo mi formulario de editar producto, el cual uso el metodo **cargarDatos()** que es el que llena los campos del JFrame.

```
private void cargarDatos() {
        obtener(idModificado);
        producto.setProducto(jtxtProducto.getText());
        producto.setCantidad(Double.valueOf(jtxtCantidad.getText()));
        producto.setPrecioCosto(Double.valueOf(jtxtPrecioCosto.getText()));
        producto.setPrecioVenta(Double.valueOf(jtxtPrecioVenta.getText()));
        producto.setMarca(jtxtMarca.getText());
        producto.setDescripcion(jtxtDescripcion.getText());
        Categoria cboCat = (Categoria)jcboCategoria.getSelectedItem();
        int idCat = cboCat.getIdcategoria();
        producto.setIdcategoria(idCat);
        Proveedor cbo = (Proveedor) jcboProveedores.getSelectedItem();
        int id = cbo.getIdproveedor();
        producto.setIdproveedor(id);
        SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String fecha = formatoFecha.format(jdcFechaVencimiento.getDate());
        producto.setFechaVencimiento(fecha);
        System.out.println(fecha);
        producto.setImage(fileImagen);
        producto.guardar();
    }
```

El método **obtener()** es el que trae lo almacenado en mi BD y le pasa por parámetros el **id** del producto.

```
public void obtener(int idProd) {
        List arrayCboCategoria = new ArrayList();
        List arrayCboProveedor = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
            CallableStatement obtenerProducto = miComando.prepareCall("call obtener_producto(?)");
            obtenerProducto.setInt(1, idProd);
            obtenerProducto.execute();
            ResultSet rs = obtenerProducto.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                jtxtIdProducto.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("idproducto")));
                jtxtProducto.setText(rs.getString("producto"));
                jtxtCantidad.setText(rs.getString("cantidad"));
                jtxtPrecioCosto.setText(rs.getString("precio_costo"));
                jtxtPrecioVenta.setText(rs.getString("precio_venta"));
                jtxtMarca.setText(rs.getString("marca"));
                jtxtDescripcion.setText(rs.getString("descripcion"));
                arrayCboCategoria.add(new Categoria(rs.getInt("idcategoria"), rs.getString("categoria")));
                arrayCboProveedor.add(new Proveedor(rs.getInt("idproveedor"), rs.getString("nombre")));
                jdcFechaVencimiento.setDate(new Date(rs.getDate("fechaVencimiento").getTime())); //Trae la fecha de la BD.
                Blob blob = rs.getBlob(13);
                if (blob != null) {
                    byte[] data = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());
                    try {
                        img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
                        ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(img);
                        lblImagenVisor.setIcon(icono);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                } else {
                    lblImagenVisor.setText("Sin Imagen");
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar obtener el producto:\n"
                    + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        if (arrayCboCategoria.size() > 0) {
            jcboCategoria.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(arrayCboCategoria.toArray()));
        }
        if (arrayCboProveedor.size() > 0) {
            jcboProveedores.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(arrayCboProveedor.toArray()));

        }
    }
```

Cuando ejecuto el proyecto y quiero editar un producto al cargar el JFrame me sale **No value specified for parameter 10** el cual corresponde a la fecha de vencimiento. Al darle aceptar al error me ejecuta el JFrame con todos los datos cargados correctamente como se puede apreciar en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero nose porque me sale ese error si al cargar el formulario me llena los campos.

Mi método **guardar** es:

```
public void guardar() {
        try {
            Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
            CallableStatement insertarProducto = miComando.prepareCall("call insertar_Producto(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            insertarProducto.setString(1, producto);
            insertarProducto.setDouble(2, cantidad);
            insertarProducto.setDouble(3, precioCosto);
            insertarProducto.setDouble(4, precioVenta);
            insertarProducto.setString(5, marca);
            insertarProducto.setString(6, descripcion);
            insertarProducto.setInt(7, idcategoria);
            insertarProducto.setInt(8, idproveedor);
            insertarProducto.setString(9, fechaVencimiento);
            if (this.image != null) {
                insertarProducto.setBinaryStream(10, image);
            }else{
                this.image = null;
            }

            if (this.idproducto != 0) {
                CallableStatement modificarProducto = miComando.prepareCall("call modificar_producto(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                modificarProducto.setInt(1, idproducto);
                modificarProducto.setString(2, producto);
                modificarProducto.setDouble(3, cantidad);
                modificarProducto.setDouble(4, precioCosto);
                modificarProducto.setDouble(5, precioVenta);
                modificarProducto.setString(6, marca);
                modificarProducto.setString(7, descripcion);
                modificarProducto.setInt(8, idcategoria);
                modificarProducto.setInt(9, idproveedor);
                modificarProducto.setString(10, fechaVencimiento);
                if (this.image != null) {
                    insertarProducto.setBinaryStream(11, image);
                }else {
                    this.image = null;
                }

                if (modificarProducto.executeUpdate() == 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Producto modificado correctamente.", "Producto modificado", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ha ocurrido un error al modificar el producto.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            } else {
                this.idproducto = insertarProducto.executeUpdate();
                if (idproducto > 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Producto guardado correctamente.", "Producto insertado", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ha ocurrido un error al guardar producto.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar almacenar el producto:\n"
                    + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Mis atributos de clase.

```
    int idproducto;
    String producto;
    double cantidad;
    double precioCosto;
    double precioVenta;
    String marca;
    String descripcion;
    int idcategoria;
    int idproveedor;
    String fechaVencimiento;
    FileInputStream image;
```

El campo fechaVecimiento es de tipo `DATETIME` en mi BD.
Mi procedimiento **obtener_producto** es:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `obtener_producto`(IN id int)
BEGIN
        SELECT P.idproducto,
                producto, 
                cantidad, 
                precio_costo,
                precio_venta, 
                marca, 
                descripcion, 
                P.idcategoria,
                C.categoria, 
                P.idproveedor,
                PV.nombre, 
                fechaVencimiento,
                imagen       
        FROM   Producto P LEFT OUTER JOIN Categoria C
        ON      P.idcategoria = C.idcategoria LEFT OUTER JOIN Proveedor PV
        ON      P.idproveedor = PV.idproveedor
        WHERE  P.idproducto=id;
END
```

La verdad no encuentro la razón del error, agradecería su ayuda. Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E podido dar con la solución que tanto me a echo perder el tiempo, por hay a alguien en alguna parte del mundo le puede servir.
Estaba trayendo la fecha truncada de la BD, lo cual hacia lo siguiente en mi método **cargarDatos()**

```
        SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String fecha = formatoFecha.format(jdcFechaVencimiento.getDate());
```

Lo cual es incorrecto porque MYSQL soporta un formato de fecha del tipo `yyyy/MM/dd` y yo lo estaba almacenando como `dd/MM/yyyy` y lo obtenía de la misma forma. Entonces probando hacer un par de cambios hice un método que retorne un String y lo asigne a mi atributo de clase, esto solo para simplificar el código e hacerlo mas prolijo. Quedaria asi:

```
    private String fecha(){
        SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        String fecha = formatoFecha.format(jdcFechaVencimiento.getDate());
        return fecha;
    }
```

En mi metodo **cargarDatos()**

```
producto.setFechaVencimiento(fecha());
```

y en mi metodo obtener quedaria igual

```
jdcFechaVencimiento.setDate(new Date(rs.getDate("fechaVencimiento").getTime()));
```

De esta forma traería la fecha como fue almacenada exactamente en la BD.

Answer (score 0):

Te puedo decir que sinceramente no deberías crear una clase para cargar el formulario, pero fuera de eso para cargar datos en un JDateChooser tienes que pesarle el date con formato de sql.Date.

y setearlo de la siguiente manera:

```
jDateChooser3.setDate(this.contrato.getFecha());
```

en el cual mi clase contrato esta trallendo un dato java.sql.Date, de esta manera te evitas tener que hacer las conversiones de fecha.

Comment: cuando te referís a **getFecha** te referís a tu atributo de clase **fecha** el cual seria de tipo `java.sql.Date` no? Porque no logro entenderte del todo! Creo que el problema este en mi método **obtener()** y no en mi método **cargarDatos()** ya que si yo hago en **println** de mi objeto `fecha` obtengo correctamente la fecha almacenada en mi BD pero sigo con ese mismo problema del **No value specified for parameter 10**

Comment: en efecto getFecha es un método del objeto contrato que instancie en mi jform, quiza, te recomiendo hace un debug paso a paso y encontraras el error rapidamente.

Comment: Si si ya e encontrado el error, estaba trayendo la fecha de forma truncada pero nunca me mostró ese error, lo descubrí cuando hice algunas modificaciones en mi código e ahí recién me salio el error real. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: no te preocupes, gracias a ti por terminar de resolverlo.
PD: por favor marca la respuesta como la solución para que los que se pasen por aquí sepan como arreglarlo :3